# Testing Network Timeouts and Errors with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, wrapper

I'm writing a wrapper for a flakey 3rd party API and would like some way to test my code's error handling.

What do people do when they want to test things like:

- API responding with various http codes (400-599)
- Connection timeouts (host is down, dns issues, etc)

Is there a correct way to do this?  Right now i'm simply using a test host, adding mod_rewrite rules such as:

```
RewriteRule ^500.html$ / [R=500,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^501.html$ / [R=501,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^404.html$ / [R=404,L,NE]
```

I then make sure my code handles those use cases appropriately but it feels wrong and provides no way to test a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be testing routes like that, I would highly suggest a combination of rspec and capybara. The rspec framework gives a lot of flexibility, and the high user base provides a ton of places for you to get started.

Comment: As far as i understand, capybara is for driving a site.  I'm looking to fake a response and fake network delay… etc.  Am i wrong?

Comment: Well, I was throwing that in because if you're going to be testing you should use that for integration tests. RSpec, using what @Sebastian mentioned above (mocha or any other mock api) would get the job done. Also check out https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs for routing specs.

Comment: I guess i don't understand how routing tests would have any relevancy when these requests are going to a 3rd party api.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to mock/stub api requests using mocha (default in rSpec), rr, flexmock etc. There are also special mocking libs for dealing with HTTP requests, but I am not sure if you can mock entire response or only body.

Comment: Something like that stub(Restclient).get { raise SocketError.new("testing network error") }, assuming that you use rr and Restclient.